# Angular could not find my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I'm trying to pass the `Id` value to my controller like this:

```
http://localhost:29045/visitorMain/?Id=afef8e80-0864-e411-8865-000c295e296b
```

But I am getting a "The resource cannot be found" error.

Here is my code below:
app.js

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('loginApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
      controller: 'loginController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/visitorMain/:Id', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/visitorMain.html',
      controller: 'visitorController'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/login'
    });
  }
]);
```

visitorController.js

```js
'use strict';
app.controller('visitorController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  //console.log(Id);
  //console.log(UserName);
  //    $scope.login = function (user) {
  //        loginService.login(user);
  //    }
});
```

Calling My visitorController

```js
 $http.get('/visitorMain/', {
   params: {
     Id: "someid"
   }
 });
```

Result:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: looks like you want to redirect then why you don't think of `$location.path('/visitorMain?Id='+someid)`

Comment: You are right. But it does not solve my problem.

Comment: only $location.path will never work you need to do `$rootScope.$apply()` then to apply digest cycle and see the effect

Comment: also you need to enable `html5mode` in angular config phase `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the hashtag. Try

```
$http.get('/#/visitorMain/', {
   params: {
     Id: "someid"
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have uncorrect url. Your controller should be like this:

```
     $http.get('/visitorMain', {
   params: {
     Id: "someid"
   }
 });
```

So your url will be: http://localhost:29045/visitorMain?Id=afef8e80-0864-e411-8865-000c295e296b.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But didnt work. Same problem. "Resource not found".

Comment: Did you add the controller file to your html page?